# Emoji buttons html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a html website and I am trying to put unicode (utf-8) emojis on it. When I try to use unicode emojis on a button it works, but I need to use the jquery attr method to set the button value, and then it just comes up as unicode letters -- how can I fix this?

```
$("#example").attr("value", "&#x1F601;");
```

(Example is a button)

```
<input type="button" name="example" id="example" value="example" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Comment: That code sets the value of the `value` attribute. But, for a button, you want the HTML contents of the button (what is in between the opening `button` tag and the closing `button` tag to be the emoji.

Comment: do i have to use a button tag?

Comment: You don't have to use a button, but initially, you indicated that you were using one. Now, your updated question explicitly says you are using a button, but you are technically not...You are using an `input` as opposed to a `button`.

Comment: It is a button just not the same kind of button.

Comment: My point is that technically it is **not** a button, it's an input element.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for your help

Comment: Of course `<input type="button">` renders a button and therefore **is** a button. He never explicitly stated that he is using an `<button>` DOM Element. The accepted answer is unsatisfying since it does not answer the original question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to render it as HTML, in which case use:

```
$("#example").html("&#x1F601;");
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/r26zzctg/)**

Comment: Yes but I want to change the button value

Comment: Use `.val()` to change the value.

Comment: .val() doesn't work. It displays the unicode letters not the emoji

Comment: Which is why you need to use `.html()` on a button element. You can still use `.val()` to set its value.

Comment: html() does nothing, it doesn't even set it to the unicode letters

Comment: Did you see the jsFiddle link on my answer?

Comment: aha the problem was I was using a differnt button tag